# tf.exe workfold "unable to determine source control server" when running as network service

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, azure-devops-server-2019

When I run the following command

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\tf.exe" workfold
```

under my local account I am getting the following:

> ======================================================================================================================= Workspace : WORSKPACENAME (USERNAME) Collection:
> http://MyTFSSERVER.local:PORTNUMBER/tfs/BLA  $/: E:\Source

But when I run the same command as nt authority\network service I am getting the error:

> Unable to determine the source control server.

How can I configure it so it will run under the user nt authority\network service?

Comment: You have a workspace mapped to that location.Network Service does not.

Comment: Some extra details, I use the network service user on a build agent. With VS 2017 tf.exe it's working fine on some machines but not with VS 2019 tf.exe. So I am looking what I need to configuge.

Comment: What's the result if we run `tf workspaces /collection:"teamCollectionUrl"` command before running `tf workfold`.